# website is not showing my wordpress site,

Tags: server, apache2, php, wordpress

Hello guys i have made website through Google Cloud with Bitnami wordpress config.
After i installed Mod_pagespeed through SSH. My website is only showing Debian default page. And I am pretty confused because it is not showing my wordpress website. and running this command shows this sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Unmonitored apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : apache not running
Syntax OK
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
Monitored apache

and my directory is on /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/ 
but website directory is on var/www something.

Comment: To me it seems like there is 2 different sites runninning and the one i just installed through apache2 is blocking the sub directory folder something.

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at slingbay.com Port 80                                            <---- for trying to browse with the site URL

Answer (score 2):

You're not wrong, your bitnami probably has it's own webserver which it starts and also uses it on port 80. Now you installed a package that installed apache2 aswell, which now blocks port 80 since it's using it.

Now your bitnami webserver cannot bind to the - in use - port 80 and fails to start.

Since your configuration is only available at the bitnami one you only get the default page which is provided in `/var/www`.

Long story short, disable and stop the newly installed apache2 service.

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service && sudo systemctl disable apache2.service
```

After that run your start script again and it should work.

Question will arise again though how you want the plugin to work if you are using the system to install it but use an externally installed apache2 service. You'll probably need to install the plugin via bitnami aswell.

Comment: Thank you i used this command instead sudo pkill -f nginx
sudo pkill -f apache
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache

Comment: Soo here is thing would be mod_pagespeed run? on my wordpress site would it make it faster if it is running externally

Comment: There are different things you have probably to do, if bitnami offers to install plugins use that. If not lookup how you can tell the bitnami apache2 which plugins it should use. The systemdefault would be a2enmod plugin name to enable the installed plugins. Now you only need to lookup how to do that on your bitnami instance.

Comment: See the [bitnami documentation on pagespeed](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/pagespeed/)